# Ошибка: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not successfully started"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Пытаюсь сохранить обьект с помощью JPA (поставщик постоянства Hibernate). В приложении есть сервлеты. Создаю `EntityManager` в классе `PersistenceManager`:

```
package com.igorgorbunov3333.persistence;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * Created by Игорь on 09.07.2016.
 */
public class PersistenceManager {

    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public static void buildEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (entityManagerFactory != null) {
            return;
        }
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("tutor-hibernate");
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static void killEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (entityManagerFactory != null) {
            entityManagerFactory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

В слушателе инициализирую `EntityManager`:

```
package com.igorgorbunov3333.web.listener;

import com.igorgorbunov3333.persistence.PersistenceManager;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

/**
 * Created by Игорь on 09.07.2016.
 */
@WebListener
public class AppListener implements ServletContextListener {


    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        PersistenceManager.buildEntityManagerFactory();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        PersistenceManager.killEntityManagerFactory();
    }
}
```

В сервлете хочу сохранить сущность `User`:

```
package com.igorgorbunov3333.web.servlet;

import com.igorgorbunov3333.entities.User;
import com.igorgorbunov3333.persistence.PersistenceManager;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Игорь on 09.07.2016.
 */
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = "/servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        PersistenceManager.getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Natan");
        user.setEmail("natan333@gmail.com");
        user.setPassword("1234");

        System.out.println(PersistenceManager.getEntityManager().getTransaction().isActive());

        PersistenceManager.getEntityManager().persist(user);
        PersistenceManager.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Строка

> System.out.println(PersistenceManager.getEntityManager().getTransaction().isActive());

показывает, что транзакция не активна. На строке

> PersistenceManager.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();

вылазит стек ошибок

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not successfully started
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:63)
>     at com.igorgorbunov3333.web.servlet.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:32)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1096)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:760)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1480)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Все ведь правильно делаю... Почемку ошибка вылазят?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в методе `PersistenceManager.getEntityManager()`. Каждый раз, когда вы его вызываете, вы создаёте новый `EntityManager`. Соответственно, методы `begin()`, `isActive()` и `commit()` вызываются на трёх разных транзакциях. Вам нужно либо переписать метод `PersistenceManager.getEntityManager()`, чтобы он не пересоздавал `EntityManager` при каждом вызове, либо не вызывать его несколько раз в одной транзакции:

```
    EntityManager entityManager = PersistenceManager.getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    ...

    entityManager.persist(user);
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: исправил, но теперь на строке entityManager.persist(user); выскакивает исключение javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement, хоть запись в базу данных и занесло....

Comment: С ConstraintViolation разобрался! Ваш ответ очень помог!